# Display compass - ArcGIS Runtime SDK - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, arcgis-runtime-net

I am using the 1st release of the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .Net - Xamarin.Forms (nuget package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Xamarin.Forms/100.0.0)).

One of the requirements is to display a compass that indicates the north. I haven't found any build-in feature for the moment. Is someone can point me out how to implement this functionality ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after few research, I've implemented a custom solution:

- Find a compass icon that can rotate (see this [article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/) to add image resource to Xamarin.Form)
- Add the image on top of the map:

  ```
  <Image x:Name="NorthArrow" />
  ```
- Rotate the image when the view point changed:

  ```
  MapView.ViewpointChanged += (sender, args) =>
  {
      NorthArrow.Rotation = -MapView.MapRotation;
  };
  ```

Complete solution [here](https://github.com/CrazyTuna/arcgis-runtime-xamarin-toolkit).